# Reverse a string

Tags: c++, strings, complexity

I use this for reversing a string, but it has O(n) :

```
reverse(y.begin(),y.end());
```

How can I reverse a string in O(n/2) ?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) While not necessarily off-topic, your question's scope is so limited (1 single expression) that there is only very little we can actually review.

Comment: Being too short has never been a reason to close. If you think there's no useful advice you can note that, but the question is not off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you're not looking for a code review and just an alternative solution on a black-box level ("gimme the better codes").

Comment: @Pimgd I'm not convinced that it is off-topic. The question is basically asking "How can I do it faster?" The answer is, essentially, "Your code is fine."

Comment: @200_success OP would not be helped by a review talking about that poor variable naming, what is `y` supposed to mean? They're looking for an alternative code snippet that will replace this one.

Answer (score 5):

You did it already: [\$O(\frac{n}{2})\$ is exactly the same as \$O(n)\$](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22188943).